# Alerting a jQuery .css property value

Tags: jquery

How to alert the value of css with jquery?

I tried:

```
alert($('#mylist').css('-moz-columns')); /* but not working */
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dcdbX/)

Comment: syntax is correct,but is the element loading when you are calling it,place it in document ready function

Comment: Run alert($("#mylist").length); to ensure that this element exists

Comment: @Cris: Check the fiddle's sidebar and you'll see that the JavaScript is run in an on-load handler.

Comment: @C-Link What browser do you use for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation for [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: `$( elem ).css( "marginTop" )` and `$( elem ).css( "marginRight" )`, and so on.

[`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) is a shorthand property for `column-count` and `column-width`.

Interestingly, it *will* work for `-webkit-columns` (in WebKit browsers only, of course).

Comment: `columns` should **not** work because it *is* a shorthand property.

Comment: The CSS code works because it is valid, but the `.css()` method in jQuery cannot deal with shorthand properties.

Comment: So how can I use -moz-column-count? like this: .css('columnCount')

Comment: Interesting it's working .css('columnCount') and also like this .css('-moz-columnCount')

Comment: It seems that `-moz-columnCount`, `columnCount`, and `webkitColumnCount` works in Firefox, IE 10, and Chrome, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

```
alert($('#mylist').css('-moz-column-count'));
```

Comment: No, you've to use -moz-column-count instead of -moz-columns... :-)

Comment: Not the comment. Amit has used -moz-column-count while you have used -moz-columns.